# DATEADD issue when negative number is used with MONTH datepart

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, dateadd

From the [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) documentation:

> If datepart is month and the date month has more days than the return
>   month and the date day does not exist in the return month, the last
>   day of the return month is returned. For example, September has 30
>   days; therefore, the two following statements return 2006-09-30
>   00:00:00.000:
>
> SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, '2006-08-30');
>
> SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, '2006-08-31');

The `SQL Server` knows that the last day of `2016-03` is `31` and the last day of the `2016-04` is `30`:

```
SELECT DAY(EOMONTH('2016-03-01')) -- 31
SELECT DAY(EOMONTH('2016-04-01')) -- 30
```

Then why the following:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, '2016-04-30')
```

returns `2016-03-30 00:00:00.000` instead `2016-03-31 00:00:00.000`?

Also, if I have the following:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, -1, '2016-03-31')
```

it correctly returns `2016-02-29 00:00:00.000`.

Comment: Answer is there in your question itself :)

Comment: ..."and the date day does not exist in the return month"... - since the 30th day does exist in march, it is correctly returning the 30th of march

Comment: if the EOMONTH function isn't enough for you and you want' to stick to some DATEADD kind of approach, you could use something like `SELECT DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, -1, GETDATE()), 0) - 1 LastDayOfMonth`

Comment: If you always need the last day of the month, always use the 31st of *a* month as your starting point. It's as simple as that. (Or, compute the 1st day of the following month instead and use `<` rather than `<=`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple workflow for dateadd function

ie. 
for Day -it's add day (next valid day) 
for week -it's add week (next 7 days)
for month -it's add month (next month only and fill forward if date is not valid)
for Year -it's add year

`SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, -1, '2016-03-31')`

output:
2016-02-29 00:00:00.000

in your example :

2016-03-31 -- 2016-02-31 (subtract 1 month) but this is not a valid date , so function try to get fill backward (in negtive) \fill forward date (in positive).
so next valid backward date is 2016-02-29.

conclude :
function is used fill forward and fill backward.

Answer (score 1):

As other comments have said, if the day of the month exists in the previous month, DATEADD will use it, and not assume that you want "the last day of the month".

If you do indeed want the "Last day of the month", you'll have to knock up a bit more logic such as:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '30 April 2016'
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, @date, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date)) = 1 THEN     DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date), 0))
        ELSE DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @date)
   END
```

That will assume that if it's the last day of the month, you want the last day of the month in the previous month, and not explicitly the 28th, 29th or 30th.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with positive numbers going from 30 -> 31 either, for example:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, '2016-09-30')
```

Yields `2016-10-30 00:00:00.000` instead of `2016-10-31 00:00:00.000`

Presumably this is because you cannot have a 31st day in a month with 30 days, it would overflow the date field, however you can have a 30th of a month in a month with 31 days just fine.

Comment: It works, you are looking for a date in a month time from starting date so the month form the 2016-09-30 is 2016-10-30. DATEADD is not designed to give you the end of month values. As it happens calculation of the month from now for dates 20xx-08-30 and 20xx-08-31 is the same date 20xx-09-30.